# Netbeans remote connection cannot connect to server

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using netBeans to develop a php application.

When I try to remote connect to the server I got this message:
Couldn't connect to server domain.com
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keyPair

I've read that if I update java it will fix the issue, but that didn't fix it.
[Screen Shot of my IDE on java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey8gz.jpg)

I'm connecting to the server by FileZilla successfully.
In FileZilla: Encryption: Requires explicit FTP over TLS.
[FileZilla Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaUOg.jpg)
I guess that's security issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. All what I did, I have uninstalled my old version 8.0 and installed version 8.1 of NetBeans.
Now it's connected now.

Comment: Having this same issue with Netbeans 8.1 but not solved